# Algorithms used for catching robots

Tags: php, webserver, web-crawler, bots

What kind of algorithm do websites, including stackexchange use to catch robots?
What makes them fail at times and present human-verification to normal users?
For web-applications and websites running on PHP, what would you recommend in order to stop robots and bot attacks and even content stealing?

Thank you.

Comment: The most powerful weapon against stolen content is the law. If people steal from you, if at all possible, consider suing them or having their sites taken down using the DMCA.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.captcha.net/ for good and easy human-verification tools.

Preventing content stealing will be really difficult as you *want* the information to be available to your visitors.

Do **not** disable right click, it will only annoy your users and not stop content thiefs in any way.

You won't be able to keep out all bots, but you will be able to implement layers of security that will each stop a part of the bots.

A few hints and tips;

- Use Captcha's for human verification, but don't use too many of them as they will tire users.
- You could do e-mail verification with a Captcha and require a login for your content (if it doesn't scare away too many users). Or consider giving some part of the content for free and require registration for the full content.
- Check for pieces of your content on other sites regularly (through Google, possibly automated with the Google API) and sue / DMCA notice if they blatantly stole (not quoted!) your content.
- Limit the speed at which individual clients can make requests to your site. Bots will scrape often and quickly. Requesting content more than once a second is already a lot for human users. There are server tools that can accomplish this, eg. check out http://www.modsecurity.org/

I am sure there are more layers of security that can be thought of, but these come to mind directly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across [an interesting article from Princeton University](http://nsg.cs.princeton.edu/publication/robot_usenix_06.pdf) that presents nice ideas for automatic robot detection. The idea is quite simple. Humans behave differently than machines, and an automated access usually does things differently than a human.

The article presents some basic checks that can be done over the course of a few requests. You spend a few requests gathering information about how the client is browsing and after some time you take all your variables and make an assertion. Things to include are:

- Mouse movement: a robot will most likely not use a mouse and therefore will not generate mouse movement events in the browser. You can prepare a javascript function, say "onBodyMouseMove()" and call it whenever the mouse moves over the entire area of page's body. If this function is called, count +1 in a session counter.
- Javascript: some robots will not take the time to run javascript (i.e. curl, wget, axel, and other command line tools), since they are mostly sending specific requests that return useful output. You can prepare a function that is called after a page is loaded and count +1 in a session counter.
- Invisble links: crawler robots are sucking machines that don't care about the content of a website. They are designed to click on all possible links and suck all the contents to a mirror location. You can insert invisible links somewhere in your webpage -- for example, a few nbsp; space characters at the bottom of the page surrounded by an anchor tag. Humans will not ever see this link, but you get a request on it, count +1 in a session counter.
- CSS, images, and other visual components: robots will most likely ignore CSS and images, because they are not interested in rendering the webpage for viewing. You can hide a link to inside an URL that ends in *.css or *.jpg (you can use Apache rewrites or servlet mappings for Java). If these specific links are accessed, it's most likely a browser loading CSS and JPG for viewing.

NOTE: *.css, *.js, *.jpg, etc are usually loaded only once per page in a session. You need to append a unique counter at the end for the browser to reload these links everytime the page is requested.

Once you gather all that information in your session over the course of a few requests, you can make an assertion. For example, if you don't see any javascript, css or mouse move activity you can assume it's a bot. It's up to you to take these counters into consideration according to your needs.. so you can program it based on these variables any way you want. If you decide some client is a robot, you can force him to solve some captcha before continuing with further requests.

Just a note: Tablets will usually not create any mouse move events. So I'm still trying to figure out how to deal with them. Suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: I was able to figure something out for tablets/smartphones. They don't have mouse movements, but their browsers have support for new JavaScript events that relate to the touching the screen. They generate events like touchstart, touchend, and touchmove. You can include the event handler `document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
 onBodyMouseMove();
}, false);` and this will cause these events to register as if the user moved the mouse over the page.